# Whats the difference between using .on('click' and .click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between .on('click') vs .click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click)

When handling a click of a div whats the difference between using .on and .click :

```
   $('#myDiv').on('click' , function(e) {
    });


    $('#myDiv').click(function(e) {
    });
```

Comment: I've read that using `.on` is faster.

Comment: As long as it's not a delegated click handler, pretty much nothing!

Comment: @adeneo What is a delegated click handler ?

Comment: It's all very well explained in the documentation, but a delegated event is used for elements that does not yet exist in the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are same...

`.click` is internally going to call `.on` method.

If you see the this part of jQuery source code.

```
jQuery.each( ("blur focus focusin focusout load resize scroll unload click dblclick " +
    "mousedown mouseup mousemove mouseover mouseout mouseenter mouseleave " +
    "change select submit keydown keypress keyup error contextmenu").split(" "), function( i, name ) {

    // Handle event binding
    jQuery.fn[ name ] = function( data, fn ) {
        if ( fn == null ) {
            fn = data;
            data = null;
        }

        return arguments.length > 0 ?
            this.on( name, null, data, fn ) :
            this.trigger( name );
    };
```

You can see that all the methods are in turn going to call `.on` method. So on will reduce your one level.

This is the implementation of `.on` in jQuery.

```
jQuery.fn.extend({

    on: function( types, selector, data, fn, /*INTERNAL*/ one ) {
        var origFn, type;

        // Types can be a map of types/handlers
        if ( typeof types === "object" ) {.....
```

Answer (score 1):

The later is a shortcut for the first.

The `.on` is more "*low-level*" and flexible. You can add a second parameter constraint the event to a selector, for example:

```
$('#myDiv').on('click' , "span.icon", function(e) {
    // this event will be fired when a click is made on a span.icon inside the #myDiv 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/click/), as of jQuery 1.7 .click():

> this method is a shortcut for `.bind("click", handler)`, as well as for
>   `.on("click", handler)`